# Redundant code inside a method in java

Tags: java, oop, methods

I was wondering if there was a way to reduce code redundace inside a simple java method. I've been running lately into issues like the following:

```
public String myMethod() {
     String errorMsg = null;

     //Do bunch of stuff, that might set errorMsg

     if (errorMsg != null) {
      return errorMsg + somethingElse;
     }

     //Do bunch of stuff, that might set errorMsg

     if (errorMsg != null) {
      return errorMsg + somethingElse;
     }

     //Do bunch of stuff, that might set errorMsg

     if (errorMsg != null) {
      return errorMsg + somethingElse;
     }
}
```

Would there be a way to maybe only write the redundant code once? Possibly write a method that would return the caller method? Or is this just a bad design? Ovsiouly there is a lot of maintenance with this code, is there a better way?

Comment: Can't you `return` immediately after setting `errorMsg` in each case?

Comment: fix your code as you repeat the same code for every if. Meaning you can simply remove 2 lower if as they will never be executed.

Comment: Where is `somethingElse` assigned?

Answer (score 3):

You want to clean your code. The below works. You can make `errorMsg` global inside your class. You can create a custom `Exception` for your needs.

```
    public String myMethod() {
        try {
            doBunchOfStuff1();
            doBunchOfStuff2();
            doBunchOfStuff3();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return e.getMessage();
        }
        return "OK";
    }

    public void doBunchOfStuff1() throws Exception {
        //
        checkError(errorMsg,somethingElse);
    }

    public void doBunchOfStuff2() throws Exception {
        //
        checkError(errorMsg,somethingElse);
    }

    public void doBunchOfStuff3() throws Exception {
        //
        checkError("Error ","something else");
    }

    public void checkError(String errorMsg, String somethingElse) throws Exception {
        if (errorMsg != null) {
            throw new Exception(errorMsg + somethingElse);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah something like this would be nice thank you very much I like it.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I think it's not a very good idea to return error message as a String (and null otherwise, is it correct?). Create a custom class called Result or something (which, probably, contains fields like boolean success and error message), or throw `Exception` with some message.

`Exceptions` behave like you described, but they not just "return the caller method" but fall through the entire call stack. You can use its feature and instead of repeating `if (error = null)` constructions you can do nothing (let them fall further with the same error message and params), or handle one by one or all of them within a big `try-catch` block, depending on design of your app.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a method that you will call when needed:

```
void error(String errorMSG, Object somethingElse){
    System.err.println(errorMSG + somethingElse); //I put a syserr, but put whatever
}
```

Then call your method whenever:

```
error("This a error", /*Something*/);
```

Answer (score 1):

### Over Engineered

```
abstract class Filter {
    public static String errorMsg = null;
    public abstract boolean check();
}

class CheckError extends Filter {
    @Override
    public boolean check() {
        return (errorMsg != null);
    }
}

abstract class DoBunchOfStuff {

    public String somethingElse = null;
    private static int counter = 0;

    public DoBunchOfStuff() {
        somethingElse = "doBunch" + ++counter;
    }

    public abstract void ofStuff(Filter filter);
}

class Follower {
    private Filter filter;
    private List<DoBunchOfStuff> stuff = new ArrayList<>();

    public Follower(Filter filter) {
        this.filter = filter;
    }

    public void add(DoBunchOfStuff bunchOf) {
        stuff.add(bunchOf);
    }

    public String call() {
        for (DoBunchOfStuff doBunch : stuff) {
            doBunch.ofStuff(filter);
            if (filter.check()) {
                return filter.errorMsg + doBunch.somethingElse;
            }
        }     
        return "OK";
    }
}

public class YourClass {

    public String myMethod() {

        Follower executor = new Follower(new CheckError());   

        DoBunchOfStuff doBunch1 = new DoBunchOfStuff() {
            @Override
            public void ofStuff(Filter filter) {
                //
            }
        };

        DoBunchOfStuff doBunch2 = new DoBunchOfStuff() {
            @Override
            public void ofStuff(Filter filter) {
                //
            }
        };

        DoBunchOfStuff doBunch3 = new DoBunchOfStuff() {
            @Override
            public void ofStuff(Filter filter) {
                //
                filter.errorMsg = "Error !!! ";
            }
        };
        executor.add(doBunch1);
        executor.add(doBunch2);
        executor.add(doBunch3);
        return executor.call();

    }
```